# About Obfuscar application use

Tags: visual-studio, obfuscar

Hello everyone: I'm learning to use this really great Obfuscar 2.2.31 in my applications made with Visual studio 2019 (C# or VB.Net).
I have done some testing and I like the results, but I want to prevent it from encrypting a class that I occupy as a model to create a generic list. I also want to exclude the encryption of a environment variable (MyPathFile).
And lastly, I am using NPOI to read excel files, how do I also exclude it from encryption?

*I have been testing with the following examples in the documentation:
`SkipField type="Full.Namespace.And.TypeName`,
`enter code here`SkipType name="Full.Namespace.And.TypeName2`,`  enter code here`SkipType name="Full.Namespace.And.TypeName3`,

`enter code here`SkipMethod type="Full.Namespace.And.TypeName3, etc.*`

but I'm not quite sure what it means: TypeName, TypeName2, TypeName3, etc..

I will be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple: I had to copy the files corresponding to the NPOI in the working folder. I solved the other problems using the following instructions:

```
<Var name="KeepPublicApi" value="true" />
<Var name="HidePrivateApi" value="false" />"
```

Great application.